# When to expose constructors of a data type when designing data structures?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, pattern-matching

When designing data structures in functional languages there are 2 options:

1. Expose their constructors and pattern match on them.
2. Hide their constructors and use higher-level functions to examine the data structures.

**In what cases, what is appropriate?**

Pattern matching can make code much more readable or simpler. On the other hand, if we need to change something in the definition of a data type then all places where we pattern-match on them (or construct them) need to be updated.

---

I've been asking this question myself for some time. Often it happens to me that I start with a simple data structure (or even a `type` alias) and it seems that constructors + pattern matching will be the easiest approach and produce a clean and readable code. But later things get more complicated, I have to change the data type definition and refactor a big part of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type is used to represent values with a canonical definition and representation (many mathematical objects fall into this category), *and* it's not possible to construct "invalid" values using the type, then you should expose the constructors.

For example, if you're representing something like two dimensional points with your own type (including a newtype), you might as well expose the constructor. The reality is that a change to this datatype is not going to be a change in how 2d points are represented, it's going to be a change in your need to use 2d points (maybe you're generalising to 3d space, maybe you're adding a concept of layers, or whatever), and is almost certain to need attention in the parts of the code using values of this type no matter what you do.[1]

A complex type representing something specific to your application or field is quite likely to undergo changes to the representation while continuing to support similar operations. Therefore you only want other modules depending on the operations, not on the internal structure. So you shouldn't expose the constructors.

Other types represent things with canonical definitions but not canonical representations. Everyone knows the *properties* expected of maps and sets, but there are lots of different ways of representing values that support those properties. So you again only want other modules depending on the operations they support, not on the particular representations.

Some types, whether or not they are if simple with canonical representations, allow the construction of values in the program which don't represent a valid value in the abstract concept the type is supposed to represent. A simple example would be a type representing a self-balancing binary search tree; client code with access to the constructors could easily construct invalid trees. Exposing the constructors either means you need to assume that such values passed in from outside may be invalid and therefore you need to make something sensible happen even for bizarre values, or means that it's the responsibility of the programmers working with your interface to ensure *they* don't violate any assumptions. It's usually better to just keep such types from being constructed directly outside your module.

Basically it comes down to the concept your type is supposed to represent. If your concept maps in a very simple and obvious[2] way directly to values in some data type which isn't "more inclusive" than the concept due to the compiler being unable to check needed invariants, then the concept is pretty much "the same" as the data type, and exposing its structure is fine. If not, then you probably need to keep the structure hidden.

---

[1] A likely change though would be to change which numeric type you're using for the coordinate values, so you probably do have to think about how to minimise the impact of such changes. That's pretty orthogonal to whether or not you expose the constructors though.

[2] "Obvious" here meaning that if you asked 10 people independently to come up with a data type representing the concept they would all come back with the same thing, modulo changing the names.

Answer (score 10):

The essential factor for me is the answer to the following question:

> Is the structure of my datatype relevant to the outside world?

For example, the internal structure of the list datatype is very much relevant to the outside world - it has an inductive structure that is certainly very useful to expose to consumers, because they construct functions that proceed by induction on the structure of the list. If the list is finite, then these functions are guaranteed to terminate. Also, defining functions in this way makes it easy to provide properties about them, again by induction.

By contrast, it is best for the `Set` datatype to be kept abstract. Internally, it is implemented as a tree in the `containers` package. However, it might as well have been implemented using arrays, or (more usefully in a functional setting) with a tree with a slightly different structure and respecting different invariants (balanced or unbalanced, branching factor, etc). The need to enforce any invariants above and over those that the constructors already enforce through their types, by the way, precludes letting the datatype be concrete.

The essential difference between the list example and the set example is that the `Set` datatype is *only* relevant for the operations that are possible on `Set`'s. Whereas lists are relevant because the standard library already provides many functions to act on them, but in addition their structure *is* relevant.

As a sidenote, one might object that actually the inductive structure of lists, which is so fundamental to write functions whose termination and behaviour is easy to reason about, is captured abstractly by two functions that consume lists: `foldr` and `foldl`. Given these two basic list operators, most functions do not need to inspect the structure of a list at all, and so it could be argued that lists too coud be kept abstract. This argument generalizes to many other similar structures, such as all `Traversable` structures, all `Foldable` structures, etc. However, it is nigh impossible to capture all possible recursion patterns on lists, and in fact many functions aren't recursive at all. Given only `foldr` and `foldl`, one would, writing `head` for example would still be possible, though quite tedious:

```
head xs = fromJust $ foldl (\b x -> maybe (Just x) Just b) Nothing xs
```

We're much better off just giving away the internal structure of the list.

One final point is that sometimes the actual representation of a datatype isn't relevant to the outside world, because say it is some kind of optimised and might not be the canonical representation, or there isn't a single "canonical" representation. In these cases, you'll want to keep your datatype abstract, but offer "views" of your datatype, which do provide concrete representations that can be pattern matched on.

One example would be if wanted to define a `Complex` datatype of complex numbers, where both cartesian forms and polar forms can be considered canonical. In this case, you would keep `Complex` abstract, but export two views, ie functions `polar` and `cartesian` that return a pair of a length and an angle or a coordinate in the cartesian plane, respectively.

Comment: Another helpful example here is a large record type where the order of fields is irrelevant, and adding fields wouldn't necessarily change the meaning of code using the type. Hiding the constructor in this case ensures other code doesn't create unnecessary dependencies, similar to the complex number example.

Comment: What if you scott-encode the list type instead of church-encoding it?  Wouldn't that allow you to define your own recursion schemes?

Comment: A nice answer. I immediately thought of [Seq](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq) when reading the last two paragraphs. Its implementation is hidden, but provides left/right views using `ViewL` and `ViewR`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the rule is pretty simple:  If it's easy to construct wrong values by using the actual constructors, then don't allow them to be used directly, but instead provide smart constructors.  This is the path followed by some data structures like `Map` and `Set`, which are easy to get wrong.

Then there are the types for which it's impossible or hard to construct inconsistent/wrong values either because the type doesn't allow that at all or because you would need to introduce bottoms.  The length-indexed list type (commonly called `Vec`) and most monads are examples of that.

Ultimately this is your own decision.  Put yourself into the user's perspective and make the tradeoff between convenience and safety.  If there is no tradeoff, then always expose the constructors.  Otherwise your library users will hate you for the unnecessary opacity.

Answer (score 5):

If the data type serves a simple purpose (like `Maybe a`) and no (explicit or implicit) assumptions about the data type can be violated by *directly* constructing a value via the data constructors, I would expose the constructors.

On the other hand, if the data type is more complex (like a balanced tree) and/or it's internal representation is likely to change, I usually hide the constructors.
When using a package, there's an unwritten rule that the interface exposed by a non-internal module should be "safe" to use on the given data type. Considering the balanced tree example, exposing the data constructors allows one to (accidentally) construct an unbalanced tree, and so the assumed runtime guarantees for searching the tree etc might be violated.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a different, noticeably more restrictive rule than most people.  The central criterion would be:

> Do you guarantee that this type will never, ever change?  If so, exposing the constructors might be a good idea.  Good luck with that, though!

But the types for which you can make that guarantee tend to be very simple, generic "foundation" types like `Maybe`, `Either` or `[]`, which one could arguably write once and then never revisit again.

Though even those can be questioned, because they do get revisited from time to time; there's people who have used Church-encoded versions of `Maybe` and `List` in various contexts for performance reasons, e.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Maybe' a = Maybe' { elimMaybe' :: forall r. r -> (a -> r) -> r }
nothing = Maybe' $ \z k -> z
just x = Maybe' $ \z k -> k x

newtype List' a = List' { elimList' :: forall r. (a -> r -> r) -> r -> r }
nil = List' $ \k z -> z
cons x xs = List' $ \k z -> k x (elimList' k z xs)
```

These two examples highlight something important: you can replace the `Maybe'` type's implementation shown above with any other implementation as long as it supports the following three functions:

```
nothing :: Maybe' a
just :: a -> Maybe' a
elimMaybe' :: Maybe' a -> r -> (a -> r) -> r
```

...and the following laws:

```
elimMaybe' nothing z x  == z
elimMaybe' (just x) z f == f x
```

And this technique can be applied to any algebraic data type.  Which to me says that pattern matching against concrete constructors is just insufficiently abstract; it doesn't really gain you anything that you can't get out of the abstract constructors + destructor pattern, and it loses implementation flexibility.

Comment: How about code readability? Even tough such code is very generic, can it be made readable the same way as pattern matching can be?

Comment: I think that, without loss of generality, we can rephrase this question as: what's a better way to consume lists, pattern matching or higher-order functions like `foldr` and friends? I vote for higher-order functions.  Which way do you vote?